# Problemas con consulta sql usando PDO en PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Estoy tratando de generar una consulta  update usando PDO, depuro la aplicación y sigue el ciclo como si todo funcionara bien, pero en realidad la consulta nos realizo.

este es el código

```
public static function updateAlistamiento($id, $fecha){
    try {
        // se crea la conexion a la base de datos 
        $pdo = Connection::getConnection(Connection::DATA_BASE2);
        $result = $pdo->prepare("
            update alistamientos 
            set estado = 7,
                respuestamt = 1,
                reportarmt = 1,
                USREPORTARMT = 'Automatico',
                USRESPUESTAMT = 'Automatico',
                freportarmt = ?
            where id = ?"
        );

        $result->bindParam(2, $id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(1, $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $result->execute();

        return ["error" => false, "message" => "", "data" => null];
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return ["error" => true, "message" => $ex->getMessage(), "data" => null];
    }
}
```

realicé una trasa para ver que pasaba con la consuta y este es l resultado:

```
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 nvarchar(4000)',N'
                update alistamientos 
                set estado = 7,
                    respuestamt = 1,
                    reportarmt = 1,
                    USREPORTARMT = ''Automatico'',
                    USRESPUESTAMT = ''Automatico'',
                    freportarmt = @P1
                where id = @P2',N'2022-04-26',N'68'
select @p1
```

cuando ejecuto la consulta en el sql magnament studio me genera el siguiente error
bug consola

```
*Msg 8179, Level 16, State 6, Procedure sp_prepexec, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
No se encontró la instrucción preparada con el identificador 1.*
```

pero al final también me muestra un mensaje como si la consulta hubiera funcionado:

```
*Completion time: 2022-04-29T09:54:35.2542426-05:00*
```

Comment: ¿Verificaste los valores de `$id`  y `$fecha` en tu contexto? ¿Cuál de los dos `return` ocurre?

Comment: Otra cosa, aunque el Manual no menciona nada al respecto, pasa los parámetros en orden. Primero: `$result->bindParam(1, $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);` y luego `$result->bindParam(2, $id,PDO::PARAM_INT);` debería ser así, al menos por coherencia.